# Unity Convert Object to Scriptable-Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, converters

How can I convert Object to `ScriptableObject` or is there a better way to load Scriptable Objects from the Resource folder?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq; 
public class ItemDatabase : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Object[] Items;
    public Item items;
 
    void Start()
    {
        Items = Resources.LoadAll("Items", typeof(Item));
 
        foreach (var t in Items)
        {
            Debug.Log(t.name);
//Convert Objects to Items
 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general [**Don't use Resources**](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7)

Make it

```
public Item[] Items;
```

put them in a normal folder and reference them via the Inspector! You can reference them all at once by selecting them all and drag them onto the `Items` **name** in the Inspector so you don't have to add them one by one.

---

If you really want to use Resources then either cast

```
Items = (Item[]) Resources.LoadAll("Items", typeof(Item));
```

Or rather use the generic version

```
Items = Resources.LoadAll<Item>("Items");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `public Object[] Items;` .

Change `Item items;` to `Item[] items;` because `Resources.LoadAll()` returns an array of objects,

and simply use the `as` keyword after `Resources.LoadAll()` to convert to your wanted type like this:

```
Items = Resources.LoadAll("Items", typeof(Item)) as Item[];
```

If the conversion was not successful `as` will return `null`.

Comment: It's actually not that tedious at all .. simply select them all a drag them onto the list name -> all added to the list, done ;)

Comment: As far is I know you have to specify the list size first then you assign them one by one .

Comment: Well I thought this until someone told me nope ;) just make sure you drop them on the list name, not the element slots .. possible though that this is only version 2020 up .. didn't try in 2019

Comment: Works in 2019 as well.

Comment: That's very time saving, thanks for the comments.